# Formatting complex table using Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, laravel, user-interface, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

I have a report card that details student academic performance,
I want to be able to create the report in html. I am using bootstrap 4 and Laravel
The report card looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l85j.png)

I have tried to use a PDF library that makes the document horizontal. The document is supposed to be 2 pages back to back. How do I implement such using bootstrap 4?

HoW Can I best replicate the table as shown in the diagram, but using HTML & Bootstrap ?

Comment: I'll assume that you have a valid reason to use an older version of Bootstrap. I think it wouldn't be too hard to recreate using the [Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Laravel.

I suggest you build the desired layout in HTML and CSS and have a look at https://wkhtmltopdf.org/. Then build a route and/ or controller, load your blade/ html output and output a pdf.